# Classes, Rvalues and Rvalue References

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

An lvalue is a value bound to a definitive region of memory whereas an rvalue is an expression value whose existence is temporary and who does not necessarily refer to a definitive region of memory. Whenever an lvalue is used in a position in which an rvalue is expected, the compiler performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and then proceeds with evaluation.

http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023341/Lvalues-and-Rvalues

Whenever we construct a temporary (anonymous) class object or return a temporary class object from a function, although the object is temporary, it is addressable. However, the object still is a valid rvalue. This means that the object is a) an addressable rvalue or b) is being implicitly converted from an lvalue to an rvalue when the compiler expects an lvalue to be used.

For instance:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A(int a) { x = a; std::cout << "int conversion ctor\n"; }
    A(A&) { std::cout << "lvalue copy ctor\n"; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "rvalue copy ctor\n"; }
};
A ret_a(A a) 
{
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    &A(5); // A(5) is an addressable object
    A&& rvalue = A(5); // A(5) is also an rvalue
}
```

We also know that temporary objects **returned** (in the following case `a`) by functions are lvalues as this code segment:

```
int main(void)
{
    ret_a(A(5));
}
```

yields the following output:

`int conversion ctor`

`lvalue copy ctor`

Indicating that the call to the function `ret_a` using actual argument `A(5)` calls the conversion constructor `A::A(int)` which constructs the function's formal argument `a` with the value 5.

When the function completes execution, it then constructs a temporary `A` object using `a` as its argument, which invokes `A::A(A&)`. However, if we were to remove `A::A(A&)` from the list of overloaded constructors, the returned temporary object would still match the rvalue-reference constructor `A::A(A&&)`.

This is what I'm not quite understanding: how can the object `a` match both an rvalue reference and an lvalue reference? It is clear that `A::A(A&)` is a better match than `A::A(A&&)` (and therefore `a` must be an lvalue). But, because an rvalue reference cannot be initialized to an lvalue, given that the formal argument `a` is an lvalue, it should not be able to match the call to `A::A(A&&)`. If the compiler is making an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion it would be trivial. The fact that a conversion from 'A' to 'A&' is also trivial, both functions should have identical implicit conversion sequence ranks and therefore, the compiler should not be able to deduce the best-matching function when both `A::A(A&)` and `A::A(A&&)` are in the overloaded function candidate set.

Moreover, the question (which I previously asked) is:

How can a given object match both an rvalue reference and an lvalue reference?

Comment: "lvalue" and "rvalue" refer to expressions, not objects.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the question then is how can the a object be bound to both rvalue and lvalue references? Also: "int n = 3; n is an expression referring to an int object. The expression n is an lvalue." http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023341/Lvalues-and-Rvalues If this is correct, then wouldn't the `a` object (above) be considered an expression in itself when being initialized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me:

```
int main(void)
{
    ret_a(A(5));
}
```

Yields:

```
int conversion ctor
rvalue copy ctor
```

(i.e. rvalue, not lvalue).  This is a bug in your compiler.  However it is understandable as the rules for this behavior changed only a few months ago (Nov. 2010).  More on this below.

> When the function completes execution,
>   it then constructs a temporary `A`
>   object using `a` as its argument, which
>   invokes `A::A(A&)`.

Actually no.  When the function `ret_a` completes execution, it then constructs a temporary `A` object using `a` as its argument, which invokes `A:A(A&&)`.  This is due to [class.copy]/p33][1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

> When the criteria for elision of a
>   copy operation are met or would be met
>   save for the fact that the source
>   object is a function parameter, and
>   the object to be copied is designated
>   by an lvalue, overload resolution to
>   select the constructor for the copy is
>   first performed as if the object were
>   designated by an rvalue. If overload
>   resolution fails, or if the type of
>   the first parameter of the selected
>   constructor is not an rvalue reference
>   to the object’s type (possibly
>   cv-qualified), overload resolution is
>   performed again, considering the
>   object as an lvalue. [ Note: This
>   two-stage overload resolution must be
>   performed regardless of whether copy
>   elision will occur. It determines the
>   constructor to be called if elision is
>   not performed, and the selected
>   constructor must be accessible even if
>   the call is elided. — end note ]

However if you remove the `A::A(A&&)` constructor, then `A::A(&)` will be chosen for the return. Although in this case, then the construction of the argument `a` will fail because you can't construct it using an rvalue.   However ignoring that for the moment, I believe your ultimate question is:

> How can a given object match both an
>   rvalue reference and an lvalue
>   reference?

in referring to the statement:

```
return a;
```

And the answer is in the above quoted paragraph from the draft standard:  First overload resolution is tried as if `a` is an rvalue.  And if that fails, overload resolution is tried again using `a` as an lvalue.  This two-stage process is tried only in the context wherein copy elision is permissible (such as a return statement).

The C++0x draft has just recently been changed to allow the two-stage overload resolution process when returning arguments that have been passed by value (as in your example).  And that is the reason for the varying behavior from different compilers that we are seeing.

Comment: @Howard thanks a bunch for the insight. But no, there were no type-o's in my original question. The call invoked `A::A(A&)`. Which compiler are you using? I'm using MSVC++

Comment: What does "or would be met save for the fact that the source
object is a function parameter," mean?

Comment: @No One:  It looks like  [class.copy]/p33 simply isn't implemented yet in your compiler.  I'm a little surprised as that particular rule is fairly old (about 4 years).  Your compiler might have an upgrade available which fixes this bug?

Comment: @Howard I'm using the latest version of MSVC++ (2010)

Comment: @Johannes:  Excellent question.  I know the intent, but now that I read the words out of context, I agree this is really awkward wording.  Fwiw, I'm innocent. ;-)  This wording was put in with cwg issue 1148 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1148) and is intended to say that parameters passed by value can be moved from if they are in the return statement, but this is not a case eligible for copy elision.  ... hmm... I'm not sure my words here are any better.  :-)

Comment: Ah I got it, I think. Someone on IRC explained it to me. Apparently it's "would be met save for the fact that ..." -> "would not be met only for the fact that ...".

Comment: @No One:  Or it could be an artifact of you calling a function and not assigning that value to anything.  Do your results change with:  A a = ret_a(A(5)); ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSVC++ but I remember that they have an ancient compatibility bug that allows rvalue to bind to lvalue references (when they were still called just references).  And I recall there is a way to turn that behavior off, but I don't recall the syntax.  Can you find that -Z whatever flag and try that?

Comment: FWIW, I just compiled that code with MSVC 2010 and GCC 4.5.2.  Both times, I got the same output as No One: `int conversion ctor` and `lvalue copy ctor`.

Comment: @Everyone:  I made a mistake in calling this "a fairly old rule".  Indeed this behavior has been mandated by the standard quite recently.  It is cwg 1148.  I had neglected to realize that the return statement was returning an argument.  Yes, the correct answer is "rvalue copy ctor".  However up until Nov. 2010 the correct answer was "lvalue copy ctor".  Sorry for all of the confusion.

Comment: I've edited my answer to try to explain the difference in behavior we're seeing among the compilers.  I just happen to be using one that's been updated since last Nov.

Comment: @Howard, before cwg 1148, function parameters were eligible for copy elision, therefor by "When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met" would require overload resolution to first consider `a` as an rvalue. Cwg 1148 just made function parameters unsuitable for copy elision, thus requiring to modify paragraph 35, which at that time was solely dependent on criteria for copy elision. Do I miss something?

Comment: I think my response was unclear.  It has never been legal to elide the copy ctor required to return a function parameter supplied by value, and returned by value, at the return statement.  Whereas it is legal to elide the copy construction at the return statement if the return statement is referring to a non-static local.  And prior to cwg 1148, implicit move in the return statement was only legal when the expression was also legal for copy elision (better known as rvo).  cwg 1148 merely says:  oh, you can implicitly move-return by-value function parameters too (but you still can't rvo them).